# ¿Solución problema pylint(no-name-in-module) / pylint(import-error)? Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Esto no afecta el funcionamiento de mi programa, pero la verdad es incomodo trabajar y que se vayan agregando más errores por lo mismo. Tengo Python 3.9 y no tengo idea de cómo solucionar esto, he intentado de todo, pero sigue estando el mismo error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crea un fichero `__init__.py` vacío en la carpeta `core`.

Comment: Hola amigo, ya lo creé y sigo con los mismos errores :(

Comment: ¿`core` tiene `__init__.py` vacío?, según veo sólo lo tiene `erp`.

Comment: En la foto no lo tenía, pero ya lo creé. Al parecer eso, junto con el comentario de abajo sirvieron. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Dentro VScode debes ir a:
File > Preferences > Settings > Workspace > Extensions > Python

Allí buscas "Python Path", y ahí debes colocar la ruta de la carpeta donde instalaste python.

Comment: Hola Javier, gracias por tu comentario. Pero ya intenté eso y no me funcionó. Esta es la ruta que puse: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

Comment: No se incluye el .exe, quedaria por ejemplo: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

Comment: Listo, ahora sí me funcionó. De verdad te agradezco